# Can someone help me to do the math?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

This might seems off topic or something, but I am a middle school student and i'm really into Quantum Field Theory and String theory and every video on youtube or article on the internet shows only the concept and Intro to these theories but I want to know about the maths envolved and do the maths myself as well , so i would love it if you guys would be suggest me a site or anything else where i can learn from scratch all the maths involved in Quantum Mechanics and maybe Einstein's Relativity as well.

Comment: Quantum Mechanics is usually introduced using a partial differential wave equation, which is solved to get eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.  The maths is similar to that for any classical system of oscillators.  Relativity is studied using four vectors in a four dimensional continuum.  General Relativity looks at relationships between four-vectors using tensor analysis.

Comment: Before diving into heavy part of physics, you should also learn some of the fundamental concepts. In that extent, I can recommend you The Feynman Lectures on Physics. You can find it in pdf on the internet pretty easily with a simple search.

Comment: You're asking for a large chunk of the mathematics in all of physics. That will take at least an entire bookshelf. This is the sort of thing that takes years of study to learn, and not just casual study but rather study to the exclusion of most everything else.